# Array change detection for an array of complex objects in Vue JS 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

**Update**

Vue JS 3 will properly handle this: https://blog.cloudboost.io/reactivity-in-vue-js-2-vs-vue-js-3-dcdd0728dcdf

**Problem:**

I have a vue component that looks like this:

sub-comp.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="textA">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="textB">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="textC">
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            textA: {
                type: Number,
                required: false
            },
            textB: {
                type: Number,
                required: false
            },
            textC: {
                type: Number,
                required: false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have a parent component that looks like this:

layout-comp.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="listItem in listItems"
                :key="listItem.id">
                <sub-comp 
                      :textA="listItem.item.textA"
                      :textB="listItem.item.textB"
                      :textC="listItem.item.textC"
                />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
import subComp from '../sub-comp.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        subComp
    },
    data() {
        return {
            listItems: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addItem: function () {
            var item = {
                         textA: 5,
                         textB: 100,
                         textC: 200
                       }
            if (!item) {
                return
            }
            this.length += 1;
            this.listItems.push({
                id: length++,
                item: item
            });
        }
    } 
</script>
```

The thing is, anything I do to edit the textboxes, the array doesn't get changed, even though the reactive data shows that it changed. For example, it will always be as

```
 { 
     textA: 5,
     textB: 100, 
     textC: 200 
 }
```

Even if I changed textB: 333, the listItems array still shows textB: 100. This is because of this:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array

**Question:**

I'm wondering how do I update the array? I also want the change to occur when leaving the textbox, using the @blur event. I'd like to see what ways this can be done.

I read these materials:

https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/array-change-detection
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

But it seems my example is a bit more complex, as it has indexes associated, and the arrays have complex objects.

---

**Update 4/12/2018**

Found out that in my addItem() that I had:

```
item = this.conditionItems[this.conditionItems.length - 1].item);
```

to

```
item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.conditionItems[this.conditionItems.length - 1].item));
```

I was thinking the sync modifier in the answer below was causing problems because it duplicated all items. But that's not the case. I was copying a vue object (including the observable properties), which caused it to happen. The JSON parse and JSON stringify methods only copies the properties as a normal object, without the observable properties. This was discussed here:

https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that props flow in one direction, from parent to child.

Setting the value using v-model in child won't affect parent's data.

Vue has a shortcut to update parent's data more easily. It's called [.sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

Here's how.

In sub-comp.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="textA" @input="$emit('update:textA', $event.target.value)" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="textB" @input="$emit('update:textB', $event.target.value)">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="textC" @input="$emit('update:textC', $event.target.value)">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // remains the same
}
</script>
```

add .sync when you add the props

```
             <sub-comp 
                  :textA.sync="listItem.item.textA" // this will have the same effect of v-on:update:textA="listItem.item.textA = $event"
                  :textB.sync="listItem.item.textB"
                  :textC.sync="listItem.item.textC"
            />
```

**update:**

if you have reactivity problem, don't use .sync, add a custom event and use $set

```
             <sub-comp 
                  :textA="listItem.item.textA" v-on:update:textA="$set('listItem.item','textA', $event)"
            />
```

Comment: Wow thank you for pointing me to this. I got certain parts of it working, I will mark as answered if I don't run into any hiccups.